# Mongo connecting to localhost although the conn string is right accross the app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So I have an Node API hosted on AWS' Beanstalk and it's connected to a DocumentDB database hosted within the same VPC, unfortunately I can't share too much info on the project since I've inherited it, but currently we have a terrible logic of creating a new db for each tenant in the system so when they sign in we create a new mongoose connection (with the proper string). Upon that there is also a global connection to a central db which is supposed to be established upon the initial start of the API - this works as expected. What doesn't work for some reason is that whenever I make a request that's supposed to go through for a certain tenant I get the following error on AWS Beanstalk logs:

[ERROR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJTHw.png)

Unfortunately, I can't fully disclose the connection strings, but I can tell you that there are no references to "locahost" within the project (noted in the picture):

[PROJECT SEARCH RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NrYF.png)

Has anyone encountered similar issues ?

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Comment: What else did you specify? `locahost` is used by default.

Comment: I fixed it. It was a issue cause by the clients database in which they determined dbhosts for different users and guess what - they were all set to localhost. The project is just ugh. Thanks anyways for the effort.